# On 9/11, was Building 7 destroyed in a controlled explosion?

Tags: politics, 9-11

There have been a lot of claims made about the circumstances surrounding the [events of 9/11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/September_11_attacks) and [Building 7 in particular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Trade_Center_controlled_demolition_conspiracy_theories#7_World_Trade_Center).

The central claim regarding [Building 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7_World_Trade_Center), that I have heard personally, is that Building 7 fell in such a perfect fluid motion that its collapse had to be due to a [controlled demolition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_demolition).  Furthermore since Building 7 wasn't hit by a plane directly, it is claimed that there can be no other explanation for how the building collapsed in such a seemingly controlled fashion.

Is there any evidence to support the claims that Building 7 was destroyed in a directly controlled fashion?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 208, accepted):

### No.

**Fires ignited by falling debris (from WTC 1) are the sole cause of the [WTC 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7_World_Trade_Center#The_original_7_World_Trade_Center_.281983.E2.80.932001.29) collapse.**

### Short answer:

- Debris from the collapse of WTC 1, about 350 ft. to the south,
  impacted WTC 7, igniting fires on at least 10 floors.
- Other than starting the fires, the debris impacts were not a
  contributing factor.
- Fires on six of those floors grew from the time of the debris
  impact (10:28:22 a.m.) and lasted until the building collapsed
  (5:20:52 p.m.).
- After several hours, the heat absorption ability of the
  fire-proofing began to fail. The building's structural steel began to
  soak up heat from the fires.
- A ''seated connection'' was used for some of the girders framed to
  interior columns. The girder was held by four "erection
  bolts" (''girders'' span between columns; ''beams'' span
  between girders).
- A 13.7 m (540 in.) long W33x130 beam heated uniformly to 600 °C will
  expand along its length by 4.5 inches.
- In doing so it will produce a lateral force of 6.9 million pounds
  (30.7 million newtons).
- The four erection bolts resisting this force had a total shear
  capacity of 0.180 million pounds (i.e., 2.6 percent of the possible
  force).
- By the time the girders reached 164 °C the four bolts had failed
  (i.e., torn in two, ripped apart, cleaved in twain, etc.).
- With the failure of the bolted connection, further thermal
  expansion of the floor beams pushed a 13<sup>th</sup> floor girder,
  between Columns 79 and 44, off its seat.
- The flooring system on Floor 13 subsequently failed, collapsing
  onto the floors below, resulting in the collapse of floors 12 through 6.
- The floor collapse left more than 150 ft. of Column 79 without
  lateral support.
- Without structure transferring load laterally, Column 79 buckled
  and failed.
- The transfer of load, once supported by Column 79, overwhelmed the
  structural capacity of the other columns. They too failed.
- After burning for 6 hours and 52 minutes, WTC 7 suffered a
  fire-induced progressive collapse. The building was completely
  destroyed.

### Long answer:

#### 1. Erection bolts are not structural connections

> In a seated connection, the beam or girder was supported by the seat,
>   which was welded to the column. Bolts were installed that fasten the
>   beam or girder to the seat for erection purposes These erection bolts
>   did not carry any gravity load; rather, they were installed to insure
>   that the beam or girder was held in place during erection. NIST found
>   no evidence that the girders or beams in WTC 7 were welded to the
>   seats. In a similar way. an angle or plate was bolted to the top
>   flange to prevent the beam or girder from twisting, but there was
>   little restraint to bending in the plane of the beam.
>   [image: NCSTAR 1-9 Figure 8-21 Page 349]
>   Consider the girder that spanned between Column 79 on the interior of
>   the building and Column 44 on the exterior. Thermal expansion of this
>   girder would have loaded the erection bolts in shear, since (1) there
>   were no shear studs anchoring the girder to the slab (and thereby
>   restraining elongation), and (2) the columns were prevented from
>   lateral movement because they were embedded in the floor slabs which
>   had considerable in-plane stiffness. Additionally, the expansion of
>   floor beams that framed into this girder, because the framing was
>   asymmetrical, tended to add additional shear load to the erection
>   bolts. The combination of these two shear loads could have failed the
>   bolts in shear. If the erection bolts were to fail, then there would
>   be no positive attachment preventing the girder from being pushed off
>   the seat. Source: [(NCSTAR 1-9) VOLUMES 1 and 2](http://www.nist.gov/customcf/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=861611), page 348.

#### 2. Thermal expansion will break stuff

> The first failures observed were of the shear studs, which were
>   produced by axial expansion of the floor beams, and which began to
>   occur at fairly low beam temperature of 103 °C. Axial expansion of the
>   girder then led to shear failure of the bolts at the connection to
>   Column 79; and, at a girder temperature of 164 °C, all four erection
>   bolts had failed, leaving that end of the girder essentially
>   unrestrained against rotation. Continued axial expansion of the floor
>   beams pushed the girder laterally at Column 79, as shown in [Figure
>   8-26](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:NIST_NCSTAR_1-9_Figure_8-26_Page_354.png), in which failed shear studs and bolts were evident. When the
>   beam temperatures had reached 300 °C, all but three shear studs in the
>   model had failed due to axial expansion of the beams, leaving the top
>   flanges of the beams essentially unrestrained laterally. Continued
>   axial expansion of the girder caused it to bear against the face of
>   Column 79, generating large axial forces that led to failure of the
>   bolts connecting the girder to Column 44. When the girder temperature
>   had reached 398 °C, all four erection bolts at Column 44 had failed,
>   leaving the girder essentially unrestrained against rotation at both
>   ends. After failure of the erection bolts in the seat at Column 44,
>   continued axial expansion of the floor beams pushed the girder
>   laterally, where it came to bear against the inside of the column
>   flange. Axial compression then increased in the floor beams, and at a
>   beam temperature of 436 °C, the northmost beam began to buckle
>   laterally. Buckling of other floor beams followed as shown in [Figure
>   8-27(a)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:NIST_NCSTAR_1-9_Figure_8-27a_Page_354.png), leading to collapse of the floor system, and rocking of the
>   girder off its seat at Column 79 as shown in [Figure 8-27(b)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:NIST_NCSTAR_1-9_Figure_8-27b_Page_354.png). The
>   collapse process took time to occur in the LS-DYNA analysis, during
>   which the temperatures had ramped up to their maximum values in the
>   simulation. Source: [(NCSTAR 1-9) VOLUMES 1 and 2](http://www.nist.gov/customcf/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=861611), page 352.

#### 3. Collapse Initiation

> The simple shear connection between Column 79 and the girder that
>   spanned the distance to the north face (to Column 44) failed on Floor
>   13. The connection failed due to shearing of erection bolts, caused by lateral thermal expansion of floor beams supporting the northeast
>   floor system and, to a lesser extent, by the thermal expansion of the
>   girder connecting Columns 79 and 44. Further thermal expansion of the
>   floor beams pushed the girder off its seat, which led to the failure
>   of the floor system surrounding Column 79 on Floor 13. The collapse of
>   Floor 13 onto the floors below-some of which were already weakened by
>   fires-triggered a cascade of floor failures in the northeast region.
>   This, in turn, led to loss of lateral support to Column 79 in the
>   east-west direction over nine stories (between Floors 5 and 14). The
>   increase in unsupported length led to the buckling failure of Column
>   79, which was the collapse initiation event. Source: [(NCSTAR 1-9)
>   VOLUMES 1 and 2](http://www.nist.gov/customcf/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=861611), page 611.

#### 4. "Free fall" is a myth

> To further clarify the descent of the north face, NIST recorded the
>   downward displacement of a point near the center of the roofline from
>   first movement until the north face was no longer visible in the
>   video. Numerical analyses were conducted to calculate the velocity and
>   acceleration of the roofline point from the time-dependent
>   displacement data. The instant at which vertical motion of the
>   roofline first occurred was determined by tracking the numerical value
>   of the brightness of a pixel (a single element in the video image) at
>   the roofline. This pixel became brighter as the roofline began to
>   descend because the color of the pixel started to change from that of
>   the building façade to the lighter color of the sky.
>
> The approach taken by NIST is summarized in [NIST NCSTAR Report
>   1A](http://www.nist.gov/manuscript-publication-search.cfm?pub_id=861610), Section 3.6, and detailed in [NIST NCSTAR Report 1-9](http://www.nist.gov/manuscript-publication-search.cfm?pub_id=861611),
>   Section 12.5.3.
>
> The analyses of the video (both the estimation of the instant the
>   roofline began to descend and the calculated velocity and acceleration
>   of a point on the roofline) revealed three distinct stages
>   characterizing the 5.4 seconds of collapse:
>
> - Stage 1 (0 to 1.75 seconds): acceleration less than that of gravity    (i.e., slower than free fall).
> - Stage 2 (1.75 to 4.0 seconds): gravitational acceleration (free fall).
> - Stage 3 (4.0 to 5.4 seconds): decreased acceleration, again less than    that of gravity.
>
> :This analysis showed that the 40 percent longer descent time—compared
>   to the 3.9 second free fall time—was due primarily to Stage 1, which
>   corresponded to the buckling of the exterior columns in the lower
>   stories of the north face. During Stage 2, the north face descended
>   essentially in free fall, indicating negligible support from the
>   structure below. This is consistent with the structural analysis
>   model, which showed the exterior columns buckling and losing their
>   capacity to support the loads from the structure above. In Stage 3,
>   the acceleration decreased as the upper portion of the north face
>   encountered increased resistance from the collapsed structure and the
>   debris pile below. Source: [Questions and Answers about the NIST WTC 7
>   Investigation](http://www.nist.gov/el/disasterstudies/wtc/faqs_wtc7.cfm).

[image: NCSTAR 1-9 Figure 12-77 Page 603]

**Claims, assertions and questions :**

Many of the claims and assertions by WTC 7 conspiracy theorists can be found at [WTC 7 Draft Reports for public comment](http://wtc.nist.gov/comments08/). The [submission by Richard Gage](http://wtc.nist.gov/comments08/richardGageAE911Truthwtc7comments.pdf) of [Architects & Engineers for 9/11 Truth](http://www.ae911truth.org/) is a good representation of how 911 conspiracy theorists rely on a *lack* of evidence to somehow draw conclusions (see: [argument from ignorance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance)).

**Investigation by the [National Institute of Standards and Technology](http://www.nist.gov/index.html)<sup>*</sup>:**

The National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST) is responsible for conducting fact-finding investigations of building failures that resulted in substantial loss of life or that posed significant potential of substantial loss of life.

[Final Report on the Collapse of World Trade Center Building 7](http://wtc.nist.gov/NCSTAR1/PDF/NCSTAR%201A.pdf)
*(The results of all NIST WTC investigations can be found at : [NIST and the World Trade Center](http://wtc.nist.gov/))*

**NIST: [Questions and Answers about the NIST WTC 7 Investigation](http://www.nist.gov/public_affairs/factsheet/wtc_qa_082108.cfm)**

> **How did the fires cause WTC 7 to
>   collapse?**
>
> The heat from the uncontrolled fires
>   caused steel floor beams and girders
>   to thermally expand, leading to a
>   chain of events that caused a key
>   structural column to fail. The failure
>   of this structural column then
>   initiated a fire-induced progressive
>   collapse of the entire building.
>
> According to the report's probable
>   collapse sequence, heat from the
>   uncontrolled fires caused thermal
>   expansion of the steel beams on the
>   lower floors of the east side of WTC
>   7, damaging the floor framing on
>   multiple floors...
>
> **How hot did WTC 7's steel columns and floor beams get?**
>
> Due to the effectiveness of the
>   spray-applied fire-resistive material
>   (SFRM) or fireproofing, the highest
>   steel column temperatures in WTC 7
>   only reached an estimated 300 degrees
>   C (570 degrees F), and only on the
>   east side of the building did the
>   steel floor beams exceed 600 degrees C
>   (1,100 degrees F). However,
>   fire-induced buckling of floor beams
>   and damage to connections-that caused
>   buckling of a critical column
>   initiating collapse-occurred at
>   temperatures below approximately 400
>   degrees C where thermal expansion
>   dominates. Above 600 degrees C (1,100
>   degrees F), there is significant loss
>   of steel strength and stiffness. In
>   the WTC 7 collapse, the loss of steel
>   strength or stiffness was not as
>   important as the thermal expansion of
>   steel structures caused by heat.
>
> **Some people have said that a failure at one column should not have produced
>   a symmetrical fall like this one.
>   What's your answer to those
>   assertions?**
>
> WTC 7's collapse, viewed from the
>   exterior (most videos were taken from
>   the north), did appear to fall almost
>   uniformly as a single unit. This
>   occurred because the interior failures
>   that took place did not cause the
>   exterior framing to fail until the
>   final stages of the building collapse.
>   The interior floor framing and columns
>   collapsed downward and pulled away
>   from the exterior frame. There were
>   clues that internal damage was taking
>   place, prior to the downward movement
>   of the exterior frame, such as when
>   the east penthouse fell downward into
>   the building and windows broke out on
>   the north face at the ends of the
>   building core. The symmetric
>   appearance of the downward fall of the
>   WTC 7 was primarily due to the greater
>   stiffness and strength of its exterior
>   frame relative to the interior
>   framing...
>
> [image: Graphic showing the buckling of WTC 7 Column 79 (circled area), the local failure identified as the initiating event in the building's progressive collapse]
>
> **Did investigators consider the possibility that an explosion caused
>   or contributed to the collapse of WTC
>   7?**
>
> Yes, this possibility was investigated
>   carefully. NIST concluded that blast
>   events inside the building did not
>   occur and found no evidence supporting
>   the existence of a blast event...
>
> **Is it possible that thermite or thermate contributed to the collapse
>   of WTC 7?**
>
> NIST has looked at the application and
>   use of thermite and has determined
>   that its use to sever columns in WTC 7
>   on 9/11/01 was unlikely.
>
> Thermite is a combination of aluminum
>   powder and a metal oxide that releases
>   a tremendous amount of heat when
>   ignited. It is typically used to weld
>   railroad rails together by melting a
>   small quantity of steel and pouring
>   the melted steel into a form between
>   the two rails...
>
> ...Analysis of the WTC steel for the
>   elements in thermite/thermate would
>   not necessarily have been conclusive.
>   The metal compounds also would have
>   been present in the construction
>   materials making up the WTC buildings,
>   and sulfur is present in the gypsum
>   wallboard used for interior
>   partitions...
>
> **An emergency responder caught in the building between the 6th and 8th
>   floors says he heard two loud booms.
>   Isn't that evidence that there was an
>   explosion?**
>
> The sound levels reported by all
>   witnesses do not match the sound level
>   of an explosion that would have been
>   required to cause the collapse of the
>   building. If the two loud booms were
>   due to explosions that were
>   responsible for the collapse of WTC 7,
>   the emergency responder-located
>   somewhere between the 6th and 8th
>   floors in WTC 7-would not have been
>   able to survive the near immediate
>   collapse and provide this witness
>   account.

---

<sup>*</sup>NIST is an agency of the U.S. Department of Commerce.

Comment: @jon_darkstar: is there anything other than the fluid motion of the collapse and the free fall speeds that would lead you to believe that explosives were involved?

Comment: i think the perfect alignment of the fall is a good indicator.  the forces on the building were far from symmetric, both the plane impact itself and the fact that columns on one side were more damaged.  on its own, that shouldnt lead to the building falling on itself so cleanly.  it would lead to a fall towards the direction of impact.

Comment: @jon_darkstar The main towers did not fail from side impact. They failed because the truss hangers for the concrete floors  seperated from their perimeter supports and the floor started dropping....bang, bang, bang...all the way down. Why straight down ? Gravity.

Comment: yes.  and the reason why this happened uniformly instead of one side heavier than the other is because of explosives.  those truss hangers couldve fell on one side alone, or one side earlier than the other, but they didnt

Comment: @jon_darkstar I can understand you might think that. Makes perfect sense. But the towers are not big poles. They are big boxes (an inner box and an outer box) and they are mostly hollow. The floors are basically just hanging between the boxes and when one comes off its hangers it can only go down. Down the inside of the box.

Comment: **Gentle but firm reminder**: comments are not the place for discussion, use the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com) for that. Thank you. :-)

Comment: we can argue finer points of that forever, so lets not.  return to the question at hand - building 7.  can you propose any reasonable explanation for it that does not involve explosives?  also, try to explain why the 911 Commission Report NEVER mentions building 7 in over 400 pages.  Not a footnote.  Nothing!  @Sklivvz - sorry, read it right after

Comment: You may want to show pictures of the SOUTH side of WTC7 prior to its collapse.  Most conspiracy theorists neglect the fact that nearly 25% of the first ten floors were missing on the south side (they only, conveniently for themselves, show the north side of the building which faced away from the collapse).  Check pages 59-66 of http://www.911myths.com/WTC7_Lies.pdf

Comment: @LarianLeQuella, as you can see in that PDF, none of the core columns were damaged in that "hole". And even if they were, it is simply impossible for the building to collapse symmetrically into it's on footprint at free fall speed from such damage and any normal fire.

Comment: @LarianLeQuella - I'm not sure where to find an image of the south-side that I'm sure is also free to use.

Comment: Re: "structural members have forces on them and the forces are not in balance". The forces ARE in balance, if the building is not moving. Otherwise the building would start moving (since `a=m/F`). That should be clarified..

Comment: @MarkRogers There are a number of pictures and videos highlighting what looks like explosive blasts 20 stories below the falling section of the tower. [See at about 30 seconds in this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13jmMfjMqm8) I'm not an engineer, so I can't give another explanation, but I have seen a few controlled demos on TV and seen a similar thing.

Comment: There's also [pictures of what looks like the support beams were cut](https://www.google.com/search?q=911+beams+cut&espv=210&es_sm=93&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=JqoXU7HOB8a8oQSYxYDYBA&ved=0CCkQsAQ&biw=1680&bih=925) ([A good example](http://www.freedomsphoenix.com/Uploads/111/Graph/wtc911_2.gif)), which is something they do in controlled demos. Something about thermite, too, but I can't verify that. It's just something that is said.

Comment: Those cut beams make absolutely no sense, as why would they be  cut at an angle if someone was using either thermite or a torch? They would be cut square around. In addition, all these images only focus on a single beam out of all of them.

Comment: @fredsbend As far as your explosive theory goes, also is already explained by this well put answer. The interior collapsed faster than the exterior, which can easily cause a bit of a 'poof' if you will like demonstrated in the video as the air between the floors rushes to escape, in addition to the force generated by the falling floors crashing into each other.

Comment: @waterseas I was answering [Mark's comment.](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1368/on-911-was-building-7-destroyed-in-a-controlled-explosion/1376?noredirect=1#comment2995_1376) This is what is often pointed to. There are dozens of pictures of cut beams; not just of the one common, most convincing one. [This is how they cut the beams in a controlled demo.](http://www.net4truthusa.com/Graphics/I-Beam-ShapeCharges.JPG)

Comment: @Waterseas One more point--in a controlled demo they remove all the windows because the air movement of the collapse could turn a window into deadly shrapnel.  That makes it very clear that a collapsing building can cause powerful air movement.

Comment: For the reasons set out in my answer below (and at the risk of inducing 9/11 fatigue) I now find this answer to be wanting.  Which is not to say it is necessarily wrong, only that I feel like the correct answer to this question ought to address the credible observations and expert opinions raised in the answer I put up, below.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt I'll add specific debunkings to credible observations as time allows.

Comment: I would edit the "sole cause" to "main cause" because that falling debris also did some extensive structural damage to WTC7, as well.

Comment: @jon_darkstar - the 9/11 commission report is about the political and bureaucratic function of government agencies in relation to the attacks, and is, in no way, a scientific analysis of the cause of the building collapses.  It was also designed to be a political butt-covering exercise.  Please refer to the NIST reports for that kind of information.  Complaining about the 9/11 commission not explaining this would be like be criticizing the US Poet Laureate for not explaining the mechanisms for ice sheet disintegration in Greenland.

Comment: Another thing I'd wonder about though is this. _If_ the building _had_ been destroyed using a "controlled explosion", _how_ would that have looked compared to what we saw actually happen? What would be seen in such a scenario we _didn't_ see in the real situation, and what (if anything) we saw in the real situation would we _not_ see in that one?

Comment: @The_Sympathizer - I know this is old, but I think that would make a great, alternative question. That's possibly the most scientific way around this.

Comment: @The Dark Side : Yes, but it would almost surely have to be asked on a different forum than this, as it's really more of a science/engineering type question than a general question about controversial claims, though of course due to the subject matter it also has some of the flavor of the latter. So I don't know where it should be posed. It might not be suitable enough for here, but there also isn't a Civil Engineering Stack Exchange, either. :)

Comment: The "debunking" of WTC 7 "conspiracy theory" seems not so clear cut after all: [A Structural Reevaluation of the Collapse of World Trade Center 7"](http://ine.uaf.edu/media/222439/uaf_wtc7_draft_report_09-03-2019.pdf)?

Comment: @gwr The linked document has not been published or undergone peer review. And given the fact that the cover page states it was "Prepared for: Architects & Engineers for 9/11 Truth", I doubt it ever will be.

Comment: @Rusty I am aware of the funding and I do not know about the integrity of A&E for 9/11 Truth (after all these should be experts in the field)? Nevertheless, arguments should always be as rational as possible - labeling sth as conspiracy theory is not rational discussion. Such a paper using simulation should indeed be peer reviewed - there are not too many papers out there being peer reviewed about WTC7, are there? Nobody wants to burn his rep probably ...

Comment: @gwr First off, I agree that rational discussion is required, therefore, I did not label the linked paper as part of a conspiracy theory. A&E for 9/11 Truth is well known for creating and supporting WTC conspiracy theories.

Comment: @gwr Next, there is in fact a large body of peer reviewed work published in a variety of professional and academic journals on the WTC failures. For example, the [journals](https://ascelibrary.org/journals) of the [American Society of Civil Engineers (ASCE)](https://www.asce.org/) alone contain a large number of papers concerning the failures of WTC 7 (along with WTC 1 & 2).

Comment: @gwr Finally, by and large members of the engineering community are only concerned with understanding why the buildings failed. E.g., Volunteer engineers from a variety of groups began investigating the failures immediately (many were on site the following day). Within days of 9/11 the board of the ASCE, a private organization, approved $500,000 for said investigations. Reputation is not a variable.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer In a controlled demolition they cut central supports so the collapse will start in the center, pulling the outsides of the building inward.  An uncontrolled fire will generally be hottest in the center of the building and the center will fail first, pulling the outside of the building inwards.

Comment: @LorenPechtel also, the walls may have a higher capacity to demand ratio because they have to deal with wind in addition to gravity. For example, in the Twin Towers, the capacity vs demand for gravity loads in the walls were around 4-5 whereas in the core it was around 2-2.5

Answer (score 19):

## No.

WTC7, like most modern skyscrapers, relied on the walls to brace it against storms. Formed of columns tied with I-beams("wind girders"), these walls formed a shell around the building.
[image]
The columns making up these walls in addition carried part of the building weight, along with columns located inside the building.

The collapse started when the northeast part of the building caved in, leaving the walls standing.

[image]

Then, the following sequence of events occurred.

1. The shift in CG caused a southwest bending moment
2. With the eastern part of the building unrestrained against north-south motion, the building twisted southwards about a western axis
3. Progressively from east to west, this bent the columns till breaking. This was aided by fire and debris impact damage, from WTC1 and adjacent structure.

You can see the twist manifest itself as a kink in the North wall some time after all columns fail

[image]

As will be shown presently, there is little reason to believe that demolition was the cause of this sequence of events.

## Why the collapse resembled a controlled demolition

When discussing the similarity of the collapse of WTC7 to a controlled demolition, 3 points are often raised.

1. **Symmetry:** The building was asymmetric. The damage was asymmetric. So how does the collapse become symmetric?
2. **Speed:** Building 7 fell at freefall for 8 storeys. How is it possible to completely lose support over 8 storeys due to a fire?
3. **Totality:** The collapse supposedly started with the failure of just one of 81 columns. So, how does such a failure bring down the whole building?

Here I shall address these features with an explanation of their causes

### Symmetry: The building collapsed from the inside out

> [image]

- As you can see, the penthouses fall first, from left to right. Then the strong facade falls as a sheet. So symmetry is an illusion.

### Symmetry: The pre collapse damage pattern

- The collapse of the Twin Towers damaged the southwest side of the building.

> [image: NCSTAR 1-9 page 161] NCSTAR 1-9 page 161

- The fire-induced collapse started in the northeast.
- Building 7 at moment of global collapse

> [image: NCSTAR 1-9 page 588 fig 12-62]
> With impact and fire damage [NCSTAR 1-9 page 588]
> [image: ![NCSTAR 1-9 page 594 fig 12-70]
> With only fire damage [page 594]

### Totality: Loss of lateral restraint from east wall

- The caving of the east flooring left the remaining structure to the west without a rigid connection to the east wall. This made the building vulnerable to twisting about the west.
- The shift in center of gravity caused by the earlier event caused a southwestward bending moment, promptly setting in motion a southward twisting. This put large bending stresses on the columns.

[image]

### Speed: The building did not fall as a rigid object

- The interior columns fell first

> [image]

- And then yanked the facade down

[image]

### Speed: Multistorey buckling

- The reaction force to the southward sway caused several lower floors to slide northward, completely undermining the building for multiple storeys.

[image]

### Totality: WTC7 was "weak"

- NIST ran a simulation without any damage other than the removal of the northeastern most interior column. The whole building collapsed.

## Why the collapse did NOT resemble a controlled demolition

### The noise

I don't know how to stress this enough. Go on Youtube and watch a controlled demolition. Odds are you'll hear:

1. A series of loud, sharp and sometimes quite annoying BANGs before the building even moves
2. A (relatively) soft and gentle roar as the building slides down

#1 was completely absent at Building 7. A vivid example of this can be seen in this video

https://youtu.be/JnLcUxV1dPo?t=126

(Ironically, this is the clip that conspiracy theorists plaster around the web)

The time delay for sound from WTC7 to arrive in this video is 2 seconds. But 7 seconds after the east side of the building implodes, we can't hear anything.

It's only after the roofline begins falling that we hear the cameramen shouting "whoa, whoa, whoa!"

### The building fell over

From this angle, you can see the building clearly fall over to the south.

https://youtu.be/JnLcUxV1dPo?t=456

[image]

Therefore, the claim that the building fell symmetrically straight down onto it's footprint is not accurate

Moreover, look at this picture of the ruins. You can see a wall draped over everything else.

[image]

## Collateral damage

Borough of Manhattan Community College lost it's Fiterman Hall in the collapse

[image]

The Verizon Building was also heavily damaged by the fall of WTC7

[image]

Not a very "controlled" demolition.

## Other steel framed buildings that fell due to fire

### The Plasco in Tehran

On 19 January 2017, the 19 storey Plasco Building pancaked following a several hours long fire.

[image]

Architects and Engineers for 9/11 Truth went so far as to claim that [this could also be a demolition!](https://www.ae911truth.org/plasco-building-collapse-in-tehran)

### Madrid Windsor Tower

This was a 32 storey building with steel walls and a concrete core

[image]

On 12 February 2005, a fire broke out, causing the steel portions, and the steel portions only, on the upper floors, to collapse.

[image]

It's possible that the collapse would have been even more destructive but an extra-strong mechanical floor at the middle of the building arrested Twin Towers style pancaking.

Comment: I was expecting that each of the four "points often raised" (three plus a bonus) would be explicitly addressed, but the structure of the explanation does not parallel the points, so it's a bit of work to make the connections.  And I don't see any explanation of the third point, nor of the bonus point.  Have I overlooked something?

Comment: And note that momentum is a big driving force in such a collapse.  The damage gets worse and worse until something gives.  That will cause a shock load to everything adjacent, making it much more likely to push it past it's failure point.  This causes an even bigger shock load to the next support.  A static analysis is basically worthless.

Comment: "MIT lost it's Fiterman Hall in the collapse" is incorrect; it was MCC or BMCC--Borough of Manhattan Community College that had the Fiterman Hall there.

Comment: @prosfilaes fixed, thank you

Answer (score 3):

## No.

I'm making this a separate answer due to the different content compared to the other one, so it can be critiqued separately.

Though not directly referenced in the question, this study is one of the strongest arguments used to claim that Building 7 was brought down by controlled demolition. Therefore, examination of this study is relevant to the question. The study concludes:

> The principal conclusion of our study is that fire did not cause the collapse of WTC 7 on 9/11, contrary to the conclusions of NIST and private engineering firms that studied the collapse. The secondary conclusion of our study is that the collapse of WTC 7 was a global failure involving the near-simultaneous failure of every column in the building.

But the study has fatal flaws. Some of the greater examples are touched upon below.

## Their result does not resemble reality

[image]

They sell their results to the layman as being "just like the real thing".

[image]

But is that really so? I want to write a refutation that a layman can understand.

Here is their global simulation compared to the real thing.

[image][image]

### They cannot replicate north wall deformation

At first, it looks quite similar. But there is an important difference. Look closely. The real building folds, and the northeast corner moves several meters north. The UAF one doesn't.

So what?

This folding is important, because it destroys their conclusion 1. Such intact floor slabs would not have permitted the kink we observe.

Why is this error important?

Because it invalidates their claims that 1. All columns failed near simultaneously (columns* 79 and 80 + unknown number of unbraced exterior columns failed long ago) and 2. The building fell straight down (the northeast corner swung North several meters).

It seems interesting, therefore, that they do not even mention the o bin n their collapse observations, shown above.

*UAF is mistaken; Column 81 did not support the east penthouse.

### They cannot explain absence of dust ejections at top floors

Here is another view of their global results

[image]

The east penthouse falls through some 5 floors before crashing to a halt. Had this happened, there would have been dust ejections from the north face as drywall was crushed and windows blown out. No such thing was observed.

Something similar may perhaps be said about the collapse of the west penthouse.

## They make strawman arguments

### No one said core column failure at the bottom won't lead to column failure at the top

In Chapter 4.3 we read:

[image][image]

In reality, the claim was:

[image]

They completely ignored the floor system failures.

### No one claimed that redistributed loads alone caused progressive core column failure

In Chapter 4.5 we read:

[image]

In reality the claim was

[image]

To be fair, it does mention load redistribution, which strikes me as asinine, since the floor system failures. However! The loss of lateral support, the impact of debris, and the collapse of the trusses, are not examined at all in the UAF study.

## Their analysis methods are flawed

### Treating the building like infinitely strong rubber

To see how plausible NIST's progressive collapse model was, UAF ran a simulation with the NIST damage model.

From their figures 4.8 to 4.16, which shows the results of their analysis of the NIST scenario, we learn that they used a linear static analysis. What does this mean?

> A linear static analysis is an analysis where a linear relation holds between applied forces and displacements. In practice, this is applicable to structural problems where stresses remain in the linear elastic range of the used material. In a linear static analysis the model’s stiffness matrix is constant, and the solving process is relatively short

[Source](https://www.femto.eu/stories/linear-non-linear-analysis-explained/)

That means they neglected plasticity and fracture in a simulation of something being destroyed. The result: Their building was indestructible; they needed to remove columns manually at each step to keep the collapse going, as shown by the captions to their figures.

### Ignoring momentum ##¥

From the above, we can see that they used a "linear static analysis". The "static" in there is particularly damning.

> Linear static analysis has two main assumptions:....

- The loading is static.

  - Magnitude and direction do not change with time.
  - All loads are applied slowly and gradually until they reach their full magnitudes. Inertial and damping properties are ignored due to negligibly small accelerations and velocities.
  - Time variant loads that induce considerable inertial and/or damping forces may warrant dynamic analysis.

[Source](https://skyciv.com/docs/structural-3d/solving/linear-static-analysis/)

By using this static model, they are ignoring all that momentum, which would play a pivotal role in a building collapse.

Here are some ways that ignoring momentum can invalidate their results

- Failing to predict the failure of components under sudden load redistribution. For example, the load increase on adjacent connections and columns when column a column fails could be magnified by up to two times due to the momentum of the structure displacing downward.
- Failing to predict component failure under impact loads. Momentum of falling debris can increase the force they apply several times.

The result of these errors can be seen in [this video](https://youtu.be/luplz1zMU7g). Watch the east penthouse kink, spring back and come to a stop on the top floors of the building.