# Destruction of WTC: is this version somehow substatinated?

Tags: united-states, 9-11, terrorism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On 911, was Building 7 destroyed in a controlled explosion?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1368/on-911-was-building-7-destroyed-in-a-controlled-explosion)

Recently I read an article that claimed that WTC in reality was blown up rather than fell due to fire. In discord with various conspiracy theories the source claims that this fact is not a secret.

The source asserts that there were in fact the terrorist acts with the planes, but also that the both towers had demolishing mechanisms embedded at the time of construction. Once the planes hit, the fire started and the most of occupiers left the buildings, the authorities together with the owner decided to blow up the buildings so to prevent greater risk.

It is further alleged that this decision and the real cause of the fall were properly reflected in the investigation documents and that anybody who wants to know the real cause and has access to restricted (but unclassified) documentation can see it.

So is there any ground behind this version?

Comment: The answer: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/1376/619 covers off all this in great detail. Flagged for closing as dupe.

Comment: In any case, it would require a link to the article. A retelling of a complicated theory is likely to contain mistakes.  Please [provide a reference](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to somewhere that this claim is being made.